# Jquery get height of element minus other element and add to css

Tags: jquery

I'm  trying to get the height of **.content_img img** then I'm trying to get the height of **#backnieuwsbrief**

When I'm having the height's I'm willing to do **.content_img img** - **#backnieuwsbrief** = **left**

now I'm trying to take the half of **left**

**left** /2 = **padd**

now get the padd and add it to the top and bottom margin of **#backnieuwsbrief**

what is going wrong?

```
$(".content_img img").load(function(){
    var max = $(this).height(); 
    var left = max - $("#backnieuwsbrief").height();
    var padd = left /2; 
    $('#backnieuwsbrief').css('padding', padd 0);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error, try

```
$('#backnieuwsbrief').css('padding', padd + 'px 0');
```